# JNI system.loadlibrary problem - native C++ dll using C library

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, dll, java-native-interface

I have a pretty annoying compiling problem.

I am trying to do a System.loadlibrary on a C++ DLL in VS2010, which in turns uses a C DLL compiled in VS2008.

The error I am getting is:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The application has failed to start because
its side-by-side configuration is incorrect

This occurs whenever my C++ DLL tries to do a call to a function in the C DLL. Both compiles just fine, and both are in a folder accessible by Java Applet.

Is this possible to solve somehow? Do you need any more info?

Comment: Are the DLL's compiled and linked in debug mode (/MDd)?  And are you running them on a machine other than the one on which you compiled?  Microsoft does not allow distribution of its debug libraries, and you can't run debug builds on a machine on which VS Studios isn't installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try and use the [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on your DLLs.
From the side-by-side error I assume that one of the c runtime redist packages or one of the noredist packages is missing.
But the dep walker should show you this.
If this does not help you can get some more information from the event log of Windows since side by side errors are logged there, or you need to use sxstrace for more info.

Comment: Dependency walker says:   MSVCR90D.DLL  and  IESHIMS.DLL   cannot be opened. Which runtime is that?

Comment: This is the debug runtime from the VS2008. So you need to install the noredist package. It should be part of the Visual Studio 2008. But I don't have the path at hand. Must be something like VC/redist/DebugNoRedist and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the runtimes of VC2010 and VC2008?

Additionally you have to make sure the manifests of both DLLs are correctly configured so that the correct version of the used library can be loaded.

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235342.aspx